# Dynamically choose which class to use within function

Tags: c#, class

Is there a way to choose which class to use in a function based on how it is called? My question is best explained by code samples:

I have 2 separate files for dealing with each type of database (SQL, Access)

Access:

```
    public static DataTable Select(string connString, string query, Dictionary<string, object> Parameters = null)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Create Query
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {

            //Add Parameters
            if (Parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in Parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }

            //Execute Query
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

SQL:

```
    public static DataTable Select(string connString, string query, Dictionary<string, object> Parameters = null)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Create Query
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {

            //Add Parameters
            if (Parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in Parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }

            //Execute Query
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Notice the only difference is the type of the Connection, Command and Adapter.

Is there a way to merge these two functions so I can pass a parameter to specify which type to use?

Comment: Actually there is another difference, `AddWithValue` is a different method in each case. In one it is `SqlDbParameterCollection.AddWithValue` and another it is `OleDbParameterCollection.AddWithValue`. To generalize you would probably have to deal with adding to a `DbParameterCollection` by creating the appropriate `DbParameter` sub-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ASKED for is called Double Dispatch. You don't need double dispatch.

```
public static DataTable Select(DbProviderFactory factory, string connString, string query, Dictionary<string, object> Parameters = null)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //Create Query
    using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        using(DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        using(DbDataAdapter da = factory.CreateDataAdapter())
        {
             cmd.CommandText = query;
             da.SelectCommand = cmd;
             if (Parameters != null)
             {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in Parameters)
                 {
                     DbParameter parameter = cmd.createParameter();
                     parameter.ParameterName = kvp.Key;
                     parameter.Value = kvp.Value;
                     cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                 }
             }
             conn.Open();
             da.Fill(dt);
             return dt;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I just needed to change the parameter part as well. The correct usage is `DbParameter parameter = cmd.createParameter()`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you could create an enumeration of database types, pass it into `Select`, and then inside `Select` you could `switch` on the value, where each case contains the corresponding code.

(However, this looks like bad design to me, since this looks like a good opportunity to use polymorphism, at least some of which you should already get through ADO.NET. You could fill the gaps yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the DbProviderFactory approach

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e(v=vs.110).aspx